# How is the F-22's nacelle/engine bay ventilated?

Tags: aircraft-systems, engine-design, inlet, f-22, f-35

How is the aircraft skin around the engine bay in the F-22 cooled?

As in the F-35, there are scoops below the wings, which provide ram air around the engine bay, but you don't see any scoop around in the F-22 for the same purpose.

[image]

Location of F-35 scoops according to [codeonemagazine.com](http://www.codeonemagazine.com/article.html?item_id=28)

Comment: Please [provide details](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/59649/edit) as to why you think there would be a cooling issue (given that the engine is a turbofan).

Comment: As in F 35 there are scoop below the wings which provide ram air around the engine bay, but you don't see any scoop around in the F 22 for the same  purpose

Comment: It's now clearer; I've moved your comment into the question, and added a photo that explains the F-35 ventilation scoops.

Answer (score 1):

The exact details of the F22 are classified. But the more likely scenario is the engine has a cold bypass air gap between the afterburner inner wall and its exterior shroud. From all the close-up shot of its nozzle, the thrust vectoring nozzle and the emergency arrestment hook fairing is lined with some sort of refractory materials and need no special cooling and the serrated nozzle fairings on either side of the nozzle seem airtight and have no place for a cooling air stream outlet. Plus, we see no scoop on the front of the aircraft as an inlet for engine cooling, and the scoop, should it exist, must be quite large. I say this is the most likely scenario because it's the least heavy and complex solution to engine cooling. And let us do not forget small cavities with a diameter in the range of millimeters is the most effective radar wave reflector/scatterer.

A less likely scenario is the engine is cooled by fuel, just like the avionics, the radar and the AC for the pilot. The fuel is then cooled first by the sheer amount of wing area as a radiator and second by a pair of hidden air-cooled fuel cooler. (I won't tell you where :))

Comment: It's not about the engine cooling, if you want the aircraft to be more stealthy the area around engine also be cooled. There are 6 diamond shaped opening in the rear bottom fuselage of the aircraft are they meant to provide air into engine bay

Comment: @AshishBhatt can you include the link to your claim in your original question?

Comment: @AshishBhatt I'm just speaking from my memory. I don't think there is an authoritative illustration of the underside of the Raptor. But from what I know that seems to be *outlets* rather than *inlets* and they seem to be the outlets of the Primary Heat Exchanger, used to cool down *bleed air* to provide air to pilot.

Comment: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/524528687823913529/  this link shows a cutaway of F 22 clearly the heat exchanger inlet and outlet are on the top, APU inlet and outlet is also on the top, ECS inlet and outlet are towards the front.

Comment: https://goo.gl/images/vEVwFk In this link if you see there are 6 openings on the bottom are they meant for bay cooling?

Comment: @AshishBhatt No, I'm sure they are not *inlet* of any kind.

Comment: @AshishBhatt i've seen this illustration multiple times, the heat exchanger is the outlet for air-cooled fuel cooler. the f22 uses *fuel* as the final liquid cooling medium  which is unlike any other fighter aircraft, so it needs a pair of massive fuel cooler unlike any other fighter aircraft.

Comment: Yes @AshishBhatt Meatball's answer (although I can't be sure in any case) is at least very convincing. Generally, any cooling that would be relegated to inlets and ducts on conventional aircraft are moved to interior bleed pipes and whatnot in stealth aircraft in order to minimize breaks in the profile. Some of my uni classes go into alternative solutions to issues that were traditionally solved with r-profile detrimental solutions, and most of them delegate air movement to bleed stolen from air ingested in the main, stealthy inlets.